# loading, editing and writing multiple data sets in R

Tags: loops

I am relatively new to R, but have so far managed through effective googling. Unfortunately, I am having a hard to resolving my current problems with google.

I have a large number of files which I would like to edit, and save as a different format. The tables contain latitude, longitude and mean temperature data in ~80,000 rows. What I need to do is select only the regions and months germane to my study. While I can do this easily enough for a single file, I cannot seem to automate the process for the 111 files I have (I would like to keep them separate, as it will be easier for downstream GIS applications).

For a single file, this is the process that works for me:

```
test<-read.fwf("air_temp.1900", widths = c(8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8), header=F)
test1<-subset(test, V1 > -135 & V1< -55 &  V2 < 80 & V2 > 55,
select=c("V1","V2","V8","V9","V10"))
write.csv(test1.csv,file="test1",row.names=F)
```

Here is an example of the data structure (the first two columns correspond to longitude and latitude, and the rest mean monthly temperatures Jan-Dec):

```
> test[1:3,]
       V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6   V7   V8  V9 V10  V11   V12   V13   V14
1 -179.75 71.25 -26.7 -19.5 -22.5 -22.3 -8.0 -0.6 2.5 0.3 -2.6  -9.6 -12.6 -23.6
2 -179.75 68.75 -28.5 -21.3 -24.4 -24.4 -8.0  0.0 4.0 0.8 -2.8 -11.1 -14.1 -26.5
3 -179.75 68.25 -29.2 -22.0 -25.2 -25.1 -8.9 -0.1 3.9 0.7 -3.4 -12.0 -14.9 -27.5
```

Here is my attempt at automating the process, though it is obviously flawed:

```
names<-list.files(pattern='air_temp.*')
names1<-substr(names,1,13)

 for(i in names2){
filepath <- file.path("...Climate.geo.udel.edu/",paste(i))
assign(i, read.fwf(filepath, widths = c(8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8), header=F))

#up to here works fine, I can automate the loading of these files into R
#but editing and exporting them doesn't seem to work

subset(i, V1 > -135 & V1 < -55 &  V2 < 80 & V2 > 55, select=c(V1,V2,V8,V9,V10))
}
```

Then the process fails with the following message: 
"Error in subset.default(i, V1 > -135 & V1 < -55 & V2 < 80 & V2 > 55, select = c(V1,  : 
  object 'V1' not found"

I can infer that "i" is not the correct object, but I cannot seem to figure out what I am supposed to put there.

I haven't even begun trying to automate the write.csv portion, so any advice on that regard would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Your error is saying that there's no variable named `V1`. This is true. `read.fwf` returns a `data.frame`. `V1` is a column in the `data.frame` held by `i` or `test`.

To use the columns of a `data.frame`, you can either use the `with` function or use the `$` syntax to access the columns in the `data.frame`.

The `with` syntax is probably simpler in your case:

```
subset(i, with(i, V1 > -135 & V1 < -55 &  V2 < 80 & V2 > 55, select=c(V1,V2,V8,V9,V10)))
```

To access each column from the variable directly, you would use this syntax:

```
i$V1
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, 'with'  function returned this error:
 Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'                       

And using $ returned this:

Error in i$V1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Try using `temp <- read.fwf(filepath, ...)` instead of `assign` and use `temp` instead of `i` for the `with`. I didn't notice before that `i` contains some part your file name. The way you're using `assign`, I think you're sticking the data in a variable named after the contents of the `i` variable, which would be a lot more difficult to use than a temporary variable.